# Oozie distro creation failed / Installing Oozie on Hadoop (AWS EC2)

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

I'm trying to get a better understanding of what's happening here. I'm really new to all this.
Oozie-5.2.1
Hadoop-3.3.5
Java openjdk version "11.0.18"

```
[INFO] ---------------< org.apache.oozie:oozie-fluent-job-api >----------------
[INFO] Building Apache Oozie Fluent Job API 5.2.1                        [2/25]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Fluent Job 5.2.1 ...................... SUCCESS [  3.232 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Fluent Job API 5.2.1 .................. FAILURE [  0.548 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client 5.2.1 .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie 5.2.1 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog 5.2.1 .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp 5.2.1 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core 5.2.1 ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming 5.2.1 ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig 5.2.1 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Git 5.2.1 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 5.2.1 .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 2 5.2.1 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop 5.2.1 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples 5.2.1 ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Spark 5.2.1 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib 5.2.1 ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs 5.2.1 ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp 5.2.1 .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools 5.2.1 ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie 5.2.1 ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Fluent Job Client 5.2.1 ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Server 5.2.1 .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro 5.2.1 .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests 5.2.1 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main 5.3.0-SNAPSHOT ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.384 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-15T05:33:39Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-fluent-job-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-fluent-job-api:jar:5.2.1: Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :oozie-fluent-job-api

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

I'm trying to following instructions from [this website](https://pollyanna-ye.github.io/2019/10/15/Install-Oozie-For-Hadoop-Workflows/).  [This] is my current pom(https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/pom.xml)

A previous error had something to do with Maven not resolving. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The error seems to be saying that Oozie cannot build with Java 11. The blog you're reading is using Java 8... Besides that, EMR already has Oozie or Airflow. Don't use EC2